# android service file read

Tags: android, service, android-service

I'm trying to make an Android App that records the user's activity(like where he touches or drags).

Because of the recent change in Android security and permissions, we can't make an app that draws over an another app and records its movements.

So our team decided to solve the problem this way

- since the adb shell's permission is **root**, we can use logcat and the grep tool to parse the logs and find what we want.
- create a service that constantly spins up logcat and saves into a file.
- create another service that reads the file logcat created, parse, and show the info.

There is currently a problem in our team.

How can we make a service that constantly reads a file and spit out the results?

After that we can do the other jobs more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a service as mentioned in below step to keep the service running all the time

1) In the service onStartCommand method return START_STICKY.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

2)Start the service in the background using startService(MyService) so that it always stays active regardless of the number of bound clients.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PowerMeterService.class);
startService(intent);
```

3)Create the binder.

```
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

4)Define a service connection.

```
private ServiceConnection m_serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            m_service = ((MyService.MyBinder)service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            m_service = null;
    }
};
```

5)Bind to the service using bindService.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
bindService(intent, m_serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

6)For your service you may want a notification to launch the appropriate activity once it has been closed.

```
private void addNotification() {
    // create the notification
    Notification.Builder m_notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.service_name))
            .setContentText(getResources().getText(R.string.service_status_monitor))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_small_icon);

    // create the pending intent and add to the notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    m_notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // send the notification
    m_notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, m_notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

7)You need to modify the manifest to launch the activity in single top mode.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

8)Note that if the system needs the resources and your service is not very active it may be killed. If this is unacceptable bring the service to the foreground using startForeground.

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, m_notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: This answer is copied from another answer. Though it is raising more complexity rather than a solution. What is 'PowerMeterService.class'? Are there two services? Why there is twon Intent with same name intent? Where to start foreground?